# How does Internationalization in ASP.NET work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization

I wonder if it is possible to make your application multilingual by simply creating resource files for every required language 
Like

```
Resource.resx for English      //string abc(name)=xyz(value)
Resource.zh.resx for Chinese   //string abc(name)=zh(value)
```

And simply placing a string in your view(single view only that support multilingual)
string like

```
@appName.Resource.abc
```

and

`<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="auto:en-GB" />`

in Web.Config

**Now my question is**

Is this enough to get started with multilingual sites i.e if I change the preferred language in my browser to Chinese the content of page is changing? But how does this work?

**What I know is**

- Browser returns preferred culture list

**Need to know**
 - How mapping to particular resource file take place. I mean both resource files (Resource.resx and Resource.zh.resx) in my example have an 'abc' property with different value. How does asp.net figure out which value to render? Is there any naming convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At run time, ASP.NET uses the resource file that is the best match for
>   the setting of the CurrentUICulture property. The UI culture for the
>   thread is set according to the UI culture of the page. For example, if
>   the current UI culture is Spanish, ASP.NET uses the compiled version
>   of the WebResources.es.resx file. If there is no match for the current
>   UI culture, ASP.NET uses resource fallback. It starts by searching for
>   resources for a specific culture. If those are not available, it
>   searches for the resources for a neutral culture. If these are not
>   found, ASP.NET loads the default resource file. In this example, the
>   default resource file is WebResource.resx.

Ref: [ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

[Microsoft .NET Internationalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096)

Comment: That means suppose if UICulture is "es" then resource.es.resx file(compiled) searched first by resourceManager?

Comment: OK thanks Mitch. one thing more, Now i want user to select preferred language once for the whole app. suggest me the easiest possible steps

Comment: @Kannas: perhaps you should make that a new question?

Comment: Mitch check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922764/internationalization-with-asp-net-mvc3user-select-preferred-language-once-for-a